# Fill an object (in React js) using results from get request using axios

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fimm my data variable with data retrieved from my axios request but when i execute i got an error .
This is my constructor where i declare my data variable :

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
             data : {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    data: []
                  }
                ]
              }

        };
      }
```

This is where im trying to fill my object

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    let responses = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      responses.push(await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transfer/getCapitalByDay/"+i).then(res =>{
          return res.data
      }))
    }
  Promise.all(responses).then(results => {
      var newData = {
        labels: results.map(day => day["day"]),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            data: results.map(amount => amount["amount"])
          }
        ]
      }
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
            data: [...prevState.data,...newData]
```

And this is the error

```
    TypeError: prevState.data is not iterable
MyBar.<anonymous>
src/component/transfer.component/bar.js:53
  50 |     return {
  51 |         
  52 | 
> 53 |           data: [...prevState.data,...newData]
```

Comment: You initialize `prevState.data` as an object in your constructor. Do you mean to do `...prevState.data.datasets` ?

Comment: no , i need to modify prev.state.data.labels and prev.state.data.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is

change

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
            data: [...prevState.data,...newData]
```

to

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
            data: {...prevState.data,...newData}
```

because in your initial state data is an object so when you try to use spread operator and pull out key-value pairs from the data object you should simply do that inside an object but not inside an array because an array cannot have key-value pairs.

btw you can just use:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, data: newData }; 
}
```

because you're overwriting every value anyway.